# How to pass a String parameter to a function from a set of allowed values

Tags: java, sql, enumeration

I'm making my own Java class called `SelectRequestBuilder` in order to easily create SQL requests. There a function `addColumnToSelect` which must take the column name as a parameter. The issue is that I want to make sure that the column name specified by the user is in the table where he want to select informations from.

So I thought that the type of the parameter `column_name` should be an `enum` like so :

```
public enum USER_COLUMN {
    ID("id"),
    USERNAME("username"),
    PASSWORD("password"),

    private final String name;
    USER_COLUMN(String name) {this.name = name;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then, in my function I could get the column name and I would be sure that the column name passed as a parameter is a valid one.

Yet, I got stuck when I wanted to be able to extend this class to not only the `users` table but to every table. What I mean is that my `SelectRequestBuilder` must be able to select values from an other table  `genders` for example. 
The reason why it's giving troubles is that my function can no longer take a parameter `column_name` of type `USER_COLUMN` because it's only for the `users` table.

Finally, my solution would be something like so:

```
private void addColumnToSelect(USER_COLUMN col) {
    addColumnToSelect(col.toString());
}

private void addColumnToSelect(GENDER_COLUMN col) {
    addColumnToSelect(col.toString());
}

private void addColumnToSelect(ROLE_COLUMN col) { // Role is an other table
    addColumnToSelect(col.toString());
}

private void addColumnToSelect(String col_name) {...}
```

But this solution is not satisfying in the sense that I must create an other function for every table in the database. This is why I ask you this question, I want your help to find a more satisfying solution ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums can implement interfaces, you can use that to your advantage:

```
interface DatabaseColumn {
  String columnName();
}


enum UserColumns implements DatabaseColumn {
  ID("id"),
  USERNAME("username"),
  PASSWORD("password");

  private final String name;

  UserColumns(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override public String columnName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Then other enums could implement the same interface, and your signature would become

```
private void addColumnToSelect(DatabaseColumn col) {

}
```